# How to calculate sum of a column and group by quarter of months (time) in InfluxDB using Flux?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

from(bucket: "bucket")
|> range(start: 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-12-31T00:00:00Z)

Answer (score 1):

Few more steps needed here:

1. Narrow down to the measurement you are interested in
2. Narrow down to the field (i.e. "column") that is going to be summed
3. Create an aggregateWindow function to track the recurring results

You could try following via Flux:

```
from(bucket: "bucket") 
    |> range(start: 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-12-31T00:00:00Z)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "MeasurementName")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "FiledKey")
    |> aggregateWindow(every : 3mo, fn : sum)
    |> yield(name: "SomeResultSetName")
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/aggregatewindow/).